# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application] - viewmodel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am creating my own viewmodel in my android app.
When the app is launched it's crashing and I got the error

> "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.app.Application]"

**1. view model class:**

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements OnCommunicationListener {
    
public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application, DeviceData deviceData) {
        super(application);

….
}
```

**2. view model factory**

```
public class ViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory {

    @NonNull
    private final Application application;
    private final DeviceData deviceData;

    public ViewModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, DeviceData deviceData) {
        super(application);
        this.application = application;
        this.deviceData = deviceData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new MainViewModel(application, deviceData);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
    }
}
```

**3. Main activity class**

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

App crashes when the following line executed in the main activity

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace of the error

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00201263911262522911

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the viewmodel factory to the `of` call or else your factory will not get used.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactoryInstance).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Thanks JensV. I'll check and get back

Comment: Great!. Its works fine. Actually I have passed this on main activity. But missed it on another activity which runs the main functionality. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice, I would appreciate an accept and upvote if I helped :)

Comment: This is deprecated in 2024

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Hilt, make sure your fragment and/or activity is annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint.  That solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks, refactored a class and forgot to add this

Comment: @Eshiet Same here :)

Comment: Thanks for saving time, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Jetpack compose and faced the same issue. To fix it

Add this to app build.gradle

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
```

and initialize viewModel like this

```
val addViewModel: AddViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, for those who are having the same error but in a multimodule project is that you forgot to add Hilt to your module.